# How to create a nested json using collections in java

Tags: java

I am creating a Json format for my nav bar menu and menu items.. i have put some effort and have done some work for one loop but what i want is to be nested json

My database  has Data like This

[image: This is my Database table]

What i want is to create a Json format from this table like this

```
        var data = {
"India":
    [
        {  "Submenu": "delhi", "link" : "https://www.google.com" },
        {  "Submenu": "mumbai", "link" : "https://www.google.com" }
    ],
"USA":
    [
        {  "Submenu": "NY", "link" : "https://www.google.com" },
        {  "Submenu": "california", "link" : "https://www.google.com" }
    ],
    "England":
        [
            {  "Submenu": "London", "link" : "https://www.google.com" },
            {  "Submenu": "Menchester", "link" : "https://www.google.com" }
        ],

"logout":
    []
```

};

Till now i have tried this

```
 LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> lhm = null;
        List<Map<Object, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<Object, Object>>();



        String sql="select menu,submenu and link from table_name";


        String name,link;
        String str = null;
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        try {

            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            while(resultSet.next()){
            lhm=    new LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>();
            name=   resultSet.getString("submenu"); 
            link=   resultSet.getString("link");
            lhm.put("submenu", name);
            lhm.put("link", link);

            list.add(lhm);  
            str = gson.toJson(list);
            }
            System.out.println(str);
```

from this i am getting result like this

```
[{"submenu":"Delhi","link":"https://www.google.com"},{"submenu":"mumbai","link":"https://www.google.com"},{"submenu":"NY","link":"https://www.google.com"},{"submenu":"California","link":"https://www.google.com"},{"submenu":"London","link":"https://www.google.com"},{"submenu":"Mencherter","link":"https://www.google.com"}]
```

now i have got the sub menus and there link .. i am facing trouble on linking the submenus to there respective menus .. i am facing issue in looping the data  acc to my requirement if anyone of you have any suggestion and idea please help me out

Comment: Can you please remove all SQL/JDBC related stuff from your code snippet as this is not relevant to your problem. Instead, please provide a short, self contained, correct example (see http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @isnot2bad i have edited ..now can you help me with solution please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First retrieve required dat from DB:

```
select menu, sub-menu, link from table_name;
```

Then create a `Map` to hold a menu content:

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Then read result sets and fill a map, using menu name as a key:

```
while(rs.next()) {
    map.compute(rs.getString("menu"), (menu, subMenus) -> {
        Map<String, String> mapSubMenu = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        mapSubMenu.put("Submenu", rs.getString("sub-menu"));
        mapSubMenu.put("link", rs.getString("link"));

        subMenus = subMenus != null ? subMenus : new ArrayList<>();
        subMenus.add(mapSubMenu);

        return subMenus;
    });
}
```

Comment: subMenus.add(mapSubMenu); here it is showing error   "The method add(Map<Object,Object>) is undefined for the type Object" this is the error

Comment: Well, I did mot check it because it is mot enough to copy paste your code to do it. Try to use debugger and find out what is wrong. Generally, it looks fine and approach is correct.

Comment: ok sir .. but its not giving me menus only giving me sub menus :(..ok i ll try

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `Map<String,List<Map<Object, Object>>>` instead of  `List<Map<Object, Object>>` so that you can give menu name to your main menu.

```
LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> lhm; //initiaze
Map<String,List<Map<Object, Object>>> map;
List<Map<Object, Object>> list;
while(rs.next())
{
    String menu = rs.getString("menu");
    String subMenu = rs.getString("sub-menu");
    String link = rs.getString("link");
        lhm.put("submenu", name);
        lhm.put("link", link);

       if (map.containsKey(menu))  //check if mainmenu already present
       {
         map.get(menu).add(lhm);  
       }
       else
        { 
         //initialize list here
         list.add(lhm);
         map.put(menu,list); 
        }

}
str = gson.toJson(list);
```

Follow idea only and customize code as your need